Problem in installing mui in nextjs project with app router and typescript
I Have created a next js project with app router, without src, with typescript. For design purpose I was trying to install mui by npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled command. But It is throwing npm error. For dependencies in package.json it is showing:
"dependencies": {
"next": "15.0.3",
"react": "19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106",
"react-dom": "19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106"
}.
I have created the project using command:  npx create-next-app
The npm error is:
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: new-project@0.1.0
npm error Found: react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   react@"19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0 || ^19.0.0" from @mui/material@6.1.8
npm error node_modules/@mui/material
npm error   @mui/material@"*" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

If I am using --force for the installation, then also so many warnings are showing. What is the reason behind it? I want to know the solution as well.

You have version 19.0.0-rc of React. First you need to downgrade react version to 18. Follow the steps:
npm uninstall react react-dom

then you need to install version 18.x.x of React (I prefer 18.2.0)
npm install react@18.2.0 react-dom@18.2.0


For now, downgrading react to 18.2.0 managed to fix this problem temporarily.
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0"


How to do that for nextjs?

npm throws an error in this situation because it doesn't consider 19.0.0-rc.* to be >=16.8.0. The maintainers recommend sticking with Next.js 14 and React 18 until the stable version of React 19 is released. Check out this GitHub PR for more details.
